# how to get latest distinct 10 records without null values using linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i want to get 10 latest(orderbydescenting datetime) records which should be unique and should not be null(ACnrAAAAAAAAAAA=) values.

sample data

```
AGMDAQo1/wSsCPU=
AGjtAAAAAAAAAAA=(this should be discarded as treating null values)
AGMDAQo1/wSsCPU=
ACnrAAAAAAAAAAA=(this should be discarded as treating null values)
AWa2AQo2CQSsCNE=
```

json data

```
[{"timestamp":"2017-03-20T05:27:01.688Z","dataFrame":"ACnrAAAAAAAAAAA=","fcnt":165,"port":3,"rssi":-85,"snr":7,"sf_used":12,"id":1489987621688,"decrypted":true},{"timestamp":"2017-03-20T05:27:41.675Z","dataFrame":"ACntAAAAAAAAAAA=","fcnt":169,"port":3,"rssi":-85,"snr":9,"sf_used":12,"id":1489987661675,"decrypted":true}]
```

desired op

```
AGMDAQo1/wSsCPU=
AWa2AQo2CQSsCNE=
```

code

```
using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
                        var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString).OrderByDescending(AssetDetail=>AssetDetail.timestamp).Take(10);
                        foreach (var item in Pirs)
                        {
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just provide a `Where` clause? You haven't mentioned what exactly you're printing to console in your example but should be something like:

```
var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetDetail>>(responseString);     
var eligibleItems = items.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA="))
                         .GroupBy(a => a.dataFrame)   
                         .Select(g=> g.First())   
                         .OrderByDescending(a => a.timestamp)
                         .Take(10);
```

Comment: i think it will remove where data like "AGjtAAAAAAAAAAA=" only, but i need to remove the records which having "AAAAAAAAAAA=" and what about distinct values.

Comment: how i will get the distict dataframe values. i need 10 unique data frames.

Comment: added - you need a grouping unless your type has custom equality already implemented

Comment: im getting same values 10 times .AGMDAQo1/wSsCPU=
AGMEAQo1/wSsCPU=. it will be considered as distict when i will get last few characters are distinct, Qo1/wSsCPU=. if the last 10 digits are unique then only its unique

Comment: you would NOT get that value 10 times with the code above

Comment: You keep changing your question and comments - just change the `GroupBy` to the condition under which you consider a string unique - you should be able to apply this answer from here or ask a new question.

Comment: sorry for that . my data contains 3 different parameters .i want last 2 parameters to be unique. which comes after 4 characters in data frame.